# n lines cut a plane into at least (n+1)(n+2)n/3 regions.

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

If a group of lines is in basic position, it means that there isn't a pair of parallel lines and each three don't intersect in a single point.

A group of $n$ lines in basic position chop the plane into regions of both infinite and finite area. The lines are given marks $1, 2, \ldots , n$. In each of the regions, we write the maximum mark written on any of its edges.

Show that the sum of the marks in all regions is at least
$(n+1)(n+2)n/3$

I've checked all $n=1,2,3,4$, now how do I prove the general case?

Comment: I believe that the "at least" in your question, and in its title, should read "at most." (A) New lines parallel to existing lines and (B) intersections of more than two lines will diminish the number.

Comment: "One Hundred Great Problems in Elementary Mathematics," the Dover Publications English translation of Dörrie's "Triumph der Mathematik," has this problem as one of its selections.

Answer (score 2):

Extended hint: Think about adding the $n^{th}$ line, using this as the basis for a proof by induction. This crosses $n-1$ other lines and therefore divides $n$ of the existing regions into two. The $n$ new regions have label $n$. The $n$ old regions have their label increased by at least $1$.

Can you see how to use this observation in an induction proof?